# Dojo: building custom configuration

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to build a custom dojo configuration.
I have to admit that I did not fully understand the official documentation.

[This tutorial](http://ivarconr.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/custom-build-in-dojo-1-7/) has been very helpful so far, though.

Here is my file-structure:

- dojo-release-1.8.3-src (untouched dojo 1.8.3 sourcecode)
- mycompany

  - app (my source files incl. html, js, css-files and compiled dojo files)
  - mycompany.profile.js
  - package.json
- release // build files should go here
- release.profile.js

**Here you can see how I execute the build script and I think the error happens on line 10**

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=XrXiUWf2

Content of my important files:

**release.profile.js**

```
 var profile = {
    basePath: "./",
    releaseDir: "./release",

    packages:[
        {
            name: "dojo",
            location: "./dojo-release-1.8.3-src/dojo"
        },
        {
            name: "dijit",
            location: "./dojo-release-1.8.3-src/dijit"
        },
        {
            name: "dojox",
            location: "./dojo-release-1.8.3-src/dojox"
        },
        {
            name: "mycompany",
            location: "./mycompany"
        }
    ]
};
```

**mycompany/package.json**

```
 {
"name": "app",
"description": "My Application",
"version": "0.1"
}
```

**mycompany/mycompany.profile.js**

```
 var profile = (function(){
  copyOnly = function(filename, mid){
    var list = {
    "mycompany/dojo.profile":1,
    "mycompany/package.json":1
    };
    return (mid in list) || /(css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|tiff)$/.test(filename);
  };

   return {

    resourceTags:{
        test: function(filename, mid){
            return false;
        },

        copyOnly: function(filename, mid){
            return copyOnly(filename, mid);
        },

        amd: function(filename, mid){
            return !copyOnly(filename, mid) && /\.js$/.test(filename);
        }
    },

    trees:[
        [".", ".", /(\/\.)|(~$)/]
    ]
  };
})();
```

I hope I have provided you with the necessary informations and we can solve the problem.
Did cost me a whole day so far.

Comment: Are your widgets "mycompany/app/MyWidget"  or "app/MyWidget"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compared to the tutorial, you include an extra directory - so a few things need to be modified.

release/profile.js

```
{
  name: "app",
  location: "./mycompany/app"
}
```

- mycompany/package.json should be moved to mycompany/app/package.json
- mycompany/mycompany.profile.js should be moved to
  mycompany/app/app.profile.js

In app.profile.js make the following change

```
var list = {
  "app/app.profile.js":1,
  "app/package.json":1
};
```